# Drools - Multiple rules fire even though they all belong to the same activation group

Tags: drools

I have a set of rules as follows:

```
rule "Default Margin By Grade"
ruleflow-group "MarginByGrade"
enabled false
when
    $mg : MarginByGrade()
    $u  : PriceUnit( resale==null, trimGrade memberOf $mg.grades  )
then    
end

rule "Grade Margin By Group, Style" extends "Default Margin By Grade"
activation-group "Margin By Grade"
salience 500
when
    MarginByGrade(this == $mg, $u.model memberOf $mg.models,  $u.style memberOf $mg.styles)
then
    System.out.println("Found match : " + $mg);
end

rule "Grade Margin By Style" extends "Default Margin By Grade"
activation-group "Margin By Grade"
salience 100
when
    MarginByGrade(this == $mg, models == null, $u.style memberOf $mg.styles)
then
    System.out.println("Found match : " + $mg);
end

rule "Grade Margin By Group" extends "Default Margin By Grade"
activation-group "Margin By Grade"
salience 50
when
    MarginByGrade(this == $mg, prefixes memberOf prefixes, styles == null)
then
    System.out.println("Found match : " + $mg);
end

rule "Margin by Grade" extends "Default Margin By Grade"
salience 5
activation-group "Margin By Grade"
when
    MarginByGrade(this == $mg, prefixes == null, styles == null)
then
    System.out.println("Found match : " + $mg);
end
```

The rules are triggered based on a Rule Flow (hence the 'ruleflow-group' attribute. My requirement is that once the rule with the highest salience fires, the rules with the lower salience should not fire. Yet when I run provide a fact that activates multiple rules, all activated rules get fired:

```
Start Process: Mon Sep 19 15:58:39 EDT 2011
Found match : MarginByGrade( prefixes=null, styles=null, grades=[C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S], margin=26.0000 )
Found match : MarginByGrade( prefixes=[015, 215], styles=[572], grades=[A, B, D], margin=25.5000 )
Found match : MarginByGrade( prefixes=[015, 010], styles=[515, 215, 572], grades=[C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S], margin=24.5000 )
015572  D 015572  D933079 FN 175->null
Dispose Session: Mon Sep 19 15:58:39 EDT 2011
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Drools Expert 5.2.0-Final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you are using activation-group and not ruleflow-group right?.. The activation-group will cause that only one rule get executed and as you mention the one with higher salience will be executed if it is activated.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only want one rule to fire (the one with the highest salience).

Comment: So which one is correct: activation-group or ruleflow-group ??

Comment: Not sure about the ruleflow, but activation-group acts as an exclusive group which you can use to solve the above mentioned issue.

Quoting documentation: 
Rules that belong to the same activation-group, identified by this attribute's string value, will only fire exclusively. In other words, the first rule in an activation-group to fire will cancel the other rules' activations, i.e., stop them from firing.

Answer (score 0):

Stateless Session:

Be-aware of activation-group in case you are working with collection of Facts and stateless session, since only one rule will fire, it would skip other facts. 
Best solution is to use Salience and a processed flag on facts

Answer (score -1):

The activation group will fire once for a single `MarginByGrade`

From your console output, you have at least 3 `MarginByGrade`, so it's correct to fire different rules for each of these 3 `MarginByGrade`